# Is it possible to download an YAML contained in a webpage using Page Objects / Capybara / Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I have a webpage that just displays a YAML file.
Is there anyway I can get that YAML file so I can save it using a cucumber project (that uses Page Object, Capybara and Selenium Webdriver and it's in Ruby).

Thanks

Comment: Seems like an overkill. Assuming this is possible, wouldn't you have to parse the HTML post download? Is there a way to get this data directly from the application instead of through the website?

Comment: Nop, the only way I have to get this info is by accessing this webpage.
What I wished to know was if there was a way to extract the YAML, instead of just html text with spaces, this way I wouldn't need to parse it back to YAML.

Comment: I don't see the HTML code. So it's difficult to answer your question. But you can get the innerText of the element that has the YAML and then parse it. You can execute Javascript with Selenium to get the innextText of an element on an HTML page

Comment: Ok, I just solved it, I'll post the solution :)

Comment: Is the webpage an HTML page that includes text that happens to be in the YAML format or is a YAML file that the browser is turning into an HTML page? If the latter you could using something like `open-uri` to directly download the YAML file.

Comment: Justin, is the second one. So how would I do that, can you please post it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just had to get the body and save its contents to a YAML file.

```
body = @browser.find_element(:tag_name => 'body')
f = File.new "#{path}/info.yml"
f.write body.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of viewing the YAML file in the browser and then having to parse the YAML out of the HTML, you can directly download the YAML file instead:

1. Determine the location of the YAML file
2. Use Open-URI to download the file

Assuming that the page has a link to the YAML file like:

```
<a href="invoice.yaml" id="invoice">Invoice Number</a>
```

Then you can download the file and save it to disk using:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'open-uri'

# Specify where to save the file
save_location = 'C:\some\file\path\name.yaml'

# Go to the page that has the link to the YAML file
page = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
page.visit('http://www.your_page.com')

# Determine the location of the YAML file
yaml_link = page.find('#invoice')
yaml_location = yaml_link['href']

# Save the file to disk
File.open(save_location, "w") do |file|
  file.puts open(yaml_location).read
end
```